Uniqueness of Poincaré metric on disk
It is well-known that the unit disk $\mathbb{D}$ admits a complete conformal metric of constant curvature $-1$, called the Poincaré metric. Is the Poincaré metric the unique metric on $\mathbb{D}$ satisfying this set of properties?
Note that completeness is necessary for uniqueness to hold, since the smaller disk $D(0, 1 / 2) \subseteq \mathbb{D}$ inherits a constant curvature metric which is not given by scaling the Poincaré metric, but also is not complete.
It is also important that the metric is conformal, since as Deane noted below, an arbitrary coordinate change produces a different metric which is still complete and has constant curvature $-1$.

Could you provide a rigorous definition of what you mean by uniqueness? Note that you can change coordinates to get a “different” metric.

@Deane Oops! I forgot to specify that the metric needs to be conformal (i.e., the way the metric measures angles is compatible with the way the complex structure measures angles).

Hint: Use the fact that all conformal automorphisms of the unit disk are isometries of the standard Poincare metric.

@MoisheKohan Could you expand a bit on this hint? I'm not sure what this tells me about an arbitrary metric $g$ which satisfies the above properties (complete, conformal, constant curvature $-1$)

Do you know that any two complete Riemannian metrics of the same constant curvature on simply connected manifolds of the same dimension are isometric?

@MoisheKohan No, I do not know that result but it would definitely answer my question. Do you have a reference for that result?

See https://www.ma.imperial.ac.uk/~dcheragh/Teaching/2016-F-GCA/2016-F-GCA-Ch2.pdf

@Deane Sorry I may be missing something, but this link doesn't say anything about Riemannian metrics?

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing%E2%80%93Hopf_theorem#:~:text=In%20geometry%2C%20the%20Killing%E2%80%93Hopf,manifolds%20are%20called%20space%20forms.

@MoisheKohan Great, thanks!

GIven an open $D \subset \mathbb{C}$, a bijective map $f: D \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is conformal if and only if it is conformal with respect to any conformally flat metrics on $D$ and $f(D)$.
